Bipartite matching where every adjacent pair of vertex on the left side of the graph has at least 1 vertex matched
The question is as stated above. I want to devise bipartite matching algorithm where it determies whether every adjacent pair of vertex on the left side of the bipartite graph has at least 1 vertex matched. In other words, for every pair $(v_i, v_{i+1})$ on the left, we want to check whether there is a matching with either $v_i$ or $v_{i+1}$ matched.
At first, I tried to modify the graph and tried to apply the flow algorithm. However, I was not able to encode the information 1) if I include vertex $v_i$, I want to tell adjacent vertices that pairwise constraints are satisfied on both 2) for every pair, it suffices for only 1 vertex to be included (i.e. formulate the graph such that if we pair up and 1 vertex is chosen, the other vertex need not be part of it / or constrained from being chosen from the pair) simultaneously. I also tried naive algorithm such as pairing up two adjacent vertex and running flow algorithm or running DP on both edge and vertex, but it did not work as well. What could be an alternative way where I can tackle this question? Thank you!!

To determine if such a matching exists is NP-complete. We reduce 3SAT to this problem of determining if there is a matching with adjacent vertices.
We create 3 gadgets:

separator gadget
variable gadget
clause gadget

Separator gadget
The separator gadget is used to ensure that there is no influence between different gadgets. It consists of one vertex in the left partite set connected to one vertex in the right partite set. Greedily, we can assume would always be always taken because it preserves valid matchings. For the following gadgets, whenever we obtain adjacent vertices from the left partite set, we assume that these are separated from other gadgets by this separator gadget.
Variable gadget
The simplest variable gadget consists of 3 adjacent vertices $v_k,v_{k+1},v_{k+2}$ in the left partite set. $v_k,v_{k+1},v_{k+2}$ are respectively connected to (distinct) $w_{v_k},w_{v_{k+1}},w_{v_{k+2}}$ in the right partite set. The effect is we have to match $(v_{k+1},w_{v_{k+1}})$ or we have to match $(v_k,w_{v_k}),(v_{k+2},w_{v_{k+2}})$.
The idea: We can form subsets $w_{x_i}$ and $w_{\lnot x_i}$ of the right partite set, where we guarantee that $w_{x_i}$ or $w_{\lnot x_i}$ is "consumed".
So far, we have demonstrated a variable gadget where $w_{x_i}=\{w_{v_k},w_{v_{k+2}}\}$ and $w_{\lnot x_i}=\{w_{v_{k+1}}\}$. We want to show that we can build arbitrarily large variable gadgets $(w_{x_i},w_{\lnot x_i})$, i.e. for any positive integer $N$, we can have $|w_{x_i}|,|w_{\lnot x_i}|>N$.
Take a variable gadget $(w_{x_i},w_{\lnot x_i})$. It suffices to construct a variable gadget $(w'_{x_i},w'_{\lnot x_i})$ with $|w'_{x_i}|=|w_{x_i}|+1,|w'_{\lnot x_i}|=|w_{\lnot x_i}|$. (The roles of $w_{x_i},w_{\lnot x_i}$ can be swapped.)
Take $w\in w_{x_i}$, and obtain three adjacent vertices in the left partite set $v'_k,v'_{k+1},v'_{k+2}$. Connect $(v'_{k+1},w)$, and obtain two more vertices in the right partite set $w_{v'_k},w_{v'_{k+2}}$, connecting $(v'_k,w_{v'_k}),(v'_{k+2},w_{v'_{k+2}})$. When we start by matching the vertices in $w_{x_i}$, we cannot match $v'_{k+1}$, and hence we have to also match $w_{v'_k}$ and $w_{v'_{k+2}}$. Our new variable gadget is $(w'_{x_i},w'_{\lnot x_i})=((w_{x_i}\setminus\{w\})\cup\{w_{v'_k},w_{v'_{k+2}}\},w_{\lnot x_i})$.
Clause gadget
For each clause $C_i=y_{i,1}\lor y_{i,2}\lor y_{i,3}$ (where $y_{i,j}$ is some variable $x_*$ or negation $\lnot x_*$), we obtain two adjacent vertices in the left partite set $v_k,v_{k+1}$ and pick fresh elements (not used in other clause gadgets) $w_{i,1}\in w_{y_{i,1}},w_{i,2}\in w_{y_{i,2}},w_{i,3}\in w_{y_{i,3}}$. Connect all of $\{v_k,v_{k+1}\}$ to all of $\{w_{i,1},w_{i,2},w_{i,3}\}$.
Proof it works
Suppose 3SAT instance is satisfiable. For each variable or negation $y\in\{x,\lnot x\}$ which is chosen to be true, only use $w_{\lnot y}$ to match the vertices in the left partite set for the variable gadget. For each satisfied clause, pick a variable which is true, and do a corresponding matching.
Suppose we have such a matching. Then from the variable gadgets, we get an assignment based on $w_{x_i}$ or $w_{\lnot x_i}$ is fully used to match the  vertices in the left partite set for the variable gadget. The construction ensures this. If both are fully used, choose arbitrarily - this variable is not used to satisfy any clause. Hence the 3SAT instance is satisfiable.
